# Chrome Web Store shows "empty-title" in URL

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

My published extension url is: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/empty-title/my-id

Why is "empty-title" showing instead of the company name? If I put the company name instead of "empty-title", it redirects to the correct page.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same issue with my packaged app.  The problem was that 'default_locale' in my manifest.json was set to 'en_US' instead of just 'en'.  Seems the webstore doesn't like it if 'en' is missing.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Yep that was it, weird. Pretty sure the documentation shows "en_US" somewhere.